# Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:

Tags: json

```
package json;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JsontoObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(
                gson.fromJson("{1,Lokesh,Gupta,[ADMIN,MANAGER]}",
                        JsontoObject.class));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed malformed. Strings must be enclosed in quotes. And curly brackets are "objects": they need keys. For instance: (don't know if that makes sense)

```
System.out.println(
        gson.fromJson("{\"one\":1,\"Lokesh\":\"Gupta\",\"array\":[\"ADMIN\",\"MANAGER\"]}",
                JsontoObject.class));
```

See also the JSON spec: http://www.json.org/